# Radius of an arch and Pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry

A door of width 6 meter has an arch above it having a height of 2 meter. Find the radius of the arch
I analysed the problem to calculate the radius of curvature and I could not establish the relation between radius and height. Please someone help me to solve this using  Pythagoras theorem on right angled triangle

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Draw a picture[image: picture]
 The radius of the arch is $r=2+h$

Comment: How can I calculate the value of h

Comment: Is h=1.25cm and r=3.25cm

Comment: That is close.  The units of the problem are meters, not centimeters.

Comment: If you extend the vertical line into a diameter, then you have $2 \times (2r-2) = 3 \times 3$ by power of a point.

Answer (score 1):

$r=2+h$
Also,
\begin{align*}
r^2 & =h^2+3^2\\
(2+h)^2 & = h^2+3^2
\end{align*}
Solving we get $h = 1.25~\text{m}$, so radius $=2+h=2+1.25= 3.25~\text{m}$

Comment: Here is [a brief introduction](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to using $\LaTeX$ in your posts to create mathematical expressions.  It has links to more extensive documentation, including the homegrown MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference.

Answer (score 0):

If radius is R, use property of circle of constant segments length product.

$$ 2 ( 2 R -2) = 3*3 \rightarrow R = \frac{13}{4}= 3.25  $$